# Binding to a nested model in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have the following model:

```
App.Checklist = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  checkitems: DS.hasMany('App.Checkitem', { embedded: true }),

  remainingItemsCount: function() {
    var checkitemsToCount = this.get('checkitems');
    return checkitemsToCount.filterProperty('isDone', false).get('length');
  }.property()

});
```

I want to display a list of checklists, with a count of the current checkitems remaining open for each list.

If I drop the following into a template, I get the correct output:

```
{{#each checklists}}
  {{this.name}}
  {{this.remainingItemsCount}}
{{/each}}
```

However, if a new checkitem is added to a checklist, the count does not go up.

BUT, if I change the `remainingItemsCount` computed property in the Checklist model so that it depends on `checkitems.@each.done`, then the count increments as new checkitems are added.

The problem is that once this dependency is added, the collection of child checkitems is wrong - it keeps repeating the first checkitem for the number of total checkitems (i.e,. if there are five items for which 'isDone' is false, and four for which 'isDone' is true, then the list count will appear as 9, and the first checkitem will be repeated 9 times).

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

It turns out that adding the dependency to the remainingItemsCount property is causing ember-data to make a new call to the server.

Without the dependency, the following XHR requests are made upon page load:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/checklists
```

With the dependency, the following XHR requests are made upon page load:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/checklists
GET http://localhost:3000/checkitems
```

The last request comes with the following parameters, which seem to be a representation of the first checkitem, wrapped in an "ids" hash:

```
{"ids"=>
  {"0"=>
    {"id"=>"182",
     "checklist_id"=>"4",
     "title"=>
      "Make sure list count automatically increments",
     "is_done"=>"false"}},
 "action"=>"index",
 "controller"=>"checkitems"}
```

I wonder if this is because the `checkitem` model is defined with a belongsTo attribute?

```
App.Checkitem = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  isDone: DS.attr('boolean'),
  checklist: DS.belongsTo('App.Checklist')
});
```

**UPDATE 2**

I'm still not certain why, but it's clear that adding the dependency to the property as follows...

```
remainingItemsCount: function() {
    var checkitemsToCount = this.get('checkitems');
    return checkitemsToCount.filterProperty('isDone', false).length;
}.property('checkitems.@each.isDone').cacheable()
```

...causes ember-data's built-in DS.RESTAdapter to call findMany.  The findMany request should take an array of ids, but instead an array containing one entire checkitem object nested inside a hash with the key 0 is being passed to it.

**SOLUTION**

In the end, I traced the problem to the following observer deep inside ember-data:

```
dataDidChange: Ember.observer(function() {
    var associations = get(this.constructor, 'associationsByName'),
        data = get(this, 'data'), store = get(this, 'store'),
        idToClientId = store.idToClientId,
        cachedValue;

    associations.forEach(function(name, association) {
      if (association.kind === 'hasMany') {
        cachedValue = this.cacheFor(name);

        if (cachedValue) {
          var ids = data.get(name) || [];
          var clientIds = Ember.ArrayUtils.map(ids, function(id) {
            return store.clientIdForId(association.type, id);
          });

          set(cachedValue, 'content', Ember.A(clientIds));
          cachedValue.fetch();
        }
      }
    }, this);
  }, 'data')
```

By the time that observer got to the line `return store.clientIdForId(association.type, id)`, the array `ids` was an array of checkitem objects, not an array of id integers.  The fix was pretty simple: `return store.clientIdForId(association.type, id.id)` returns an array of id integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a JSFiddle from your description and couldn't reproduce your problem. I'm using Ember.js 0.9.6 and the latest build of ember-data, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/dGjyR/

**Handlebars**:

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="checklist" >
    {{#each checklists}}
      {{this.name}}
      remaining: {{this.remainingItemsCount}}
      {{#each checkitems}}
        {{view Ember.Checkbox valueBinding="isDone"}}
      {{/each}}
      <a {{action "addCheckitem"}} class="clickable">add item</a>
      <hr/>
    {{/each}}

</script>​
```

**JavaScript**:

```js
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.Checkitem = DS.Model.extend({
    isDone: DS.attr('boolean')
});

App.Checklist = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),

    checkitems: DS.hasMany('App.Checkitem', {
        embedded: true
    }),

    remainingItemsCount: function() {
        var checkitemsToCount = this.get('checkitems');
        return checkitemsToCount.filterProperty('isDone', false).get('length');
    }.property('checkitems.@each.isDone').cacheable()
});

App.store = DS.Store.create({
    revision: 4
});

App.checklistsController = Ember.ArrayProxy.create({
    content: App.store.find(App.Checklist)
});

Ember.View.create({
    templateName: 'checklist',
    checklistsBinding: 'App.checklistsController',
    addCheckitem: function(evt) {
        var checklist = evt.context;
        checklist.get('checkitems').addObject(App.Checkitem.createRecord({
            isDone: false
        }));
    }
}).append();


var checklist = App.Checklist.createRecord({
    name: 'firstChecklist'
});

App.Checklist.createRecord({
    name: 'secondChecklist'
});

checklist.get('checkitems').addObject(App.Checkitem.createRecord({
    isDone: false
}));
checklist.get('checkitems').addObject(App.Checkitem.createRecord({
    isDone: true
}));
checklist.get('checkitems').addObject(App.Checkitem.createRecord({
    isDone: true
}));​
```

Comment: That really helped!  Thanks.  It turns out that adding the dependency causes ember-data to call the server's "/checkitems" url with a hash representing one of the checkitems.  I have no idea why, but that's almost certainly the reason the ArrayProxy of checkitems is turning up wrong.

Comment: I wonder if this is because the checkitem model has a `checklist: DS.belongsTo('App.Checklist')` attribute.  I can't figure out why the server would be called.  I never set a url for the checkitem DS.Model.

Comment: But you use a `DS.RESTAdapter`? Because this one figures your URL's automatically. Maybe that's why you get a call to your server.

Comment: Yes, this is using the built in DS.RESTAdapter.  I'll tear into that to see if I can trace the issue.  Maybe I need to roll my own.